# Custom Events across multiple jQuery instances

Tags: jquery, events, publish-subscribe

Let's assume the following situation:

- the page (http://somedomain.com/somepage.html) has jQ 1.9 loaded.
- it also loads our script http://ourservice.com/script.js
- which in turn loads jQ 1.7 in noConflict mode

Now there's jQ 1.9 available to the page itself and used by some scripts on that page and there's jQ 1.7 used internally in our `script.js`.

Now from the `script.js` we want to trigger some event on an element:

```
$el.trigger('our_event.ns');
```

As far as I understand this event does not reach the other instance of jQ (1.9) — right? At least it looks so from our tests.

Any way to make it work without implementing pub/sub in our code instead of relying on jQ's?

Comment: events are bound to the element, JQ version is irrelevant. Only relevance are the handlers when event is triggered

Comment: I don't get your comment. Event is bound to in 1 _copy_ of jQ and triggered in another

Comment: example where event handler assigned in one version and other version triggers event  http://plnkr.co/edit/wLKqrdRMbT80ZtPfxur2?p=preview. Element has no idea the 2 jQuery versions exist

Comment: yeah, cool... Now the same with custom events (as said in the question): http://plnkr.co/edit/MFRKdWg76nZgG0pZ1evr?p=preview

Comment: OK.. yes, might be ok with custom events. jQuery used to store them on element in $(element).data('events'), but now store them in $._data('events')

Comment: so `_data` doesn't reach DOM or is persisted in a different way? any ideas how to make the above example work?

Comment: $._data is property of jQuery object